# How to include tests from root project directory in pip package, such that other pip packages can call it?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

### Context

After creating a project directory with the following folder structure:

```py
src/snnalgorithms__main__.py
tests/some_test.py
tests/some_dir/other_test.py
```

and publishing it as a pip package, I receive the error:

```
from snnalgorithms.tests.sparse.MDSA.test_snn_results import Test_mdsa_snn_results
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snnalgorithms.tests'
```

when I try to call that test file from another pip package/python code/project. I would expect this error, because I did not tell the `setup.py` (with content) and the `setup.cfg` that the `pip` package should include the `tests` directory.

### setup.py

```py
"""Packaging logic for snnalgorithms."""
from __future__ import annotations

import os
import sys

import setuptools

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "src"))
# sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "tests"))

install_requires = [
    "lava @ https://github.com/a-t-0/lava/archive/refs/tags/v0.5.1.tar.gz",
]
setuptools.setup()
```

### setup.cfg

```
[metadata]
name = snnalgorithms
version = attr: snnalgorithms.__version__
description = compares snn algorithms against neumann algorithms
long_description = file: README.md
long_description_content_type = text/markdown
url = https://github.com/a-t-0/snnalgorithms
author = a-t-0
author_email = no-email@no-email.org
maintainer = a-t-0
maintainer_email = no-email@no-email.org
license = AGPLv3
license_file = licence
classifiers =
    Development Status :: 2 - Pre-Alpha
    Environment :: Console
    Intended Audience :: Science/Research
    License :: OSI Approved :: GNU Affero General Public License v3
    Programming Language :: Python
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3 :: Only
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10
    Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: Artificial Intelligence

[options]
packages = find:
package_dir =
    =src
# Dependencies
install_requires =
    jsons>=1.6.3
    matplotlib>=3.6.1
    networkx>=2.8.7
    numpy>=1.23.4
    pyannotate>=1.2.0
    pytest-cov>=4.0.0
    typeguard>=2.13.3
python_requires = >=3.10

[options.packages.find]
where = src

[options.entry_points]
console_scripts =
    snnalgorithms = snnalgorithms:main

[bdist_wheel]
universal = 1

[mypy]
check_untyped_defs = true
disallow_any_generics = true
disallow_incomplete_defs = true
disallow_untyped_defs = true
no_implicit_optional = true
warn_unused_ignores = true

[mypy-tests.*]
disallow_untyped_defs = false
```

### Update based on comments

Based on the comments I learned that it is not desireable/conventional to include the tests in the pip package that is installed by the users. Instead one can differentiate between a `wheel` and `sdist` distribution of pip. I believe the `wheel` contains the MWE pip package for users, whereas the `sdist` may also include the tests.

### Question

How can one include the tests in the root directoy of a repo, into the pip package, such that other pip packages are able to use/import those tests?

Comment: **1.** Is `projectname` in `src/projectname/__main__.py` just `snnalgorithms`? **2.** Python packaging tools don't implement magic; if you want `tests` to be distributed with `snnalgorithms` you need to move `tests/` into `src/snnalgorithms/`.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Thank you, since the `tests/` directory at the root dir seems to be conventional (e.g. https://github.com/PyCQA/flake8),  I thought there would be a way to tell pip to include that `tests` folder in the root dir. However it is good to know that that is not possible.

Comment: `flake8` doesn't pack `tests/` in wheels but they pack it in source distributions. You can check that downloading files from https://pypi.org/project/flake8/#files . They did that (include `tests/` in sdist) using [`MANIFEST.in`](https://github.com/PyCQA/flake8/blob/b9a7794c4f425ef8419081e6993f99419cc667ea/MANIFEST.in#L7). Later they [removed the file](https://github.com/PyCQA/flake8/commit/cf6d3fe0c6faf7a8a3835ba97edac3238c8b1edc), I don't know how they changed their publishing process.

Comment: On the other hand I include tests in my distributions: [SQLObject](https://github.com/sqlobject/sqlobject/tree/db162aa7542a1be03d8a3a5f93f17038d7979ead/sqlobject/tests), [CheetahTemplate](https://github.com/CheetahTemplate3/cheetah3/tree/402d473752147811a455a64ac854f2e686d4287c/Cheetah/Tests).

Comment: Do you want the tests to be installed on the user's machines? I believe a typical pattern is to have the tests in the sdist but not in the wheel(s). This way users can have the tests if they want them,  but they are not installed (in `site-packages`). -- WIth *setuptools*, if you rename the `tests` directory to `test` then this directory is automatically added to the sdist (but not the wheel).

Comment: @sinoroc Thank you I was not aware of the difference, and will look into how to differentiate between installing the two versions (`sdist` and `wheel`) such that other packages can use the tests from the respective (`sdist`) pip package, without installing the tests on the users device. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Then it is as I said, you can rename `tests` to `test` and you should be done. If you do not want to rename, then add `tests` into the `MANIFEST.in` file. Docs: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/using-manifest-in/#using-manifest-in and https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/miscellaneous.html#controlling-files-in-the-distribution and https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/deprecated/distutils/sourcedist.html#specifying-the-files-to-distribute

Comment: But from my point of view, tests should not be "importable". So when I see in your question the error message `from snnalgorithms.tests.sparse.MDSA.test_snn_results import Test_mdsa_snn_results` I am wondering what is going on here, this is a red flag to me. Also when I see `sys.path` manipulations this is a red flag. I do not know how you run your test suite, maybe that is the issue.